# Invoke a Service through Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to consume the service from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts in angular 2

My html is as under

```
employee-information-apps.html
--------------------------------
<button (click)="getDetails()" id="tbn1">Invoke Service</button>
```

### app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">     
      <employee-selector></employee-selector>
    </div>
  `,  
})
// Component controller
export class App { 
  constructor() { }
}

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'employee-selector',
  templateUrl: 'employee-information-apps.html'   
})

// Component controller
export class EmployeeInformation {

  http: Http;
  constructor(private _http: Http) {

    this.http = http;
    this.url='http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';


  }//end constructor      

      getDetails(){

             return this._http.get(this.url)
                    .map((response: Response) => Console.log(response.json()))
                    .catch(this.handleError);   
    } //end getDetails

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App,EmployeeInformation ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But I could not make this work.

What is the mistake that I am making?

[image]

Comment: Any error messages? I see you aren't subscribing to `getDetails`. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `HttpModule`in your `NgModule`

Here in your **app.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule // <--- here!
  ],
  declarations: [ App,EmployeeInformation ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And also, you are missing `Http` and `Response` import.

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EjxRfxLVGQcjcCOjP05m?p=preview)

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar answer edited, you also need to import `Http` and `Response`

Comment: No..still error.. a demo in jsfiddle or plunker will be helpful so that i can figure out what is that i am missing..

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Added plunker link

Answer (score 1):

You never `subscribed`. The observer is "cold" until activated with a subscribe.

```
return this._http.get(this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => Console.log(response.json()))
    .subscribe(result => {
        // this.posts = result;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Are you including `http` in your systemJS?

Comment: yes i am...would you mind to demo it in plunker so that i can figure out what is that i am  missing